# Big-O Complexity of $2^\sqrt{\log n}$

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

How can I simplify $2^\sqrt{\log n}$ to determine the Big O complexity?

I have seen a proof for $2^{\log_2n} = O(n)$ by applying $\log_2$ to both sides ($\log_2 y = \log_2 2^{\log_2 n}$), bringing the exponent to the left ($\log_2 y = \log_2 n \log_2 2$), then since $\log_2 2 =1$, and $\log_2 y = \log_2 n$, $y=n$.

I can follow this logic to a similar step of $\log_2 y = \sqrt{\log_2 n}$, but was not sure if I can take this further. By squaring both sides I believe I end up with $(\log_2y)^2 = \log_2 n$ then ($\log_2 y \times \log_2 y) = \log_2 n$, but I am unsure if I can simplify this further, I'm not the best with logarithms but cannot seem to find a satisfactory answer online.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this expression can’t be simplified. But I’m open to being corrected on that. Out of curiosity, which algorithm has this runtime?

Comment: Its growth is superlogarithmic and subpolynomial as you can check.

Comment: Thank you both, that was what I was getting to but I wasn't sure if I was missing something more obvious.